# how to set WebBrowser proxy

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, browser

I am making a multi-threaded application. Each thread has its own WebBrowser control. I want to know how to set a different proxy for each WebBrowser. A custom WebBrowser that supports a proxy per instance will be a good solution to me as well.

Comment: You have multiple UI threads? How did you do that?

Comment: They ain't UI threads. They are a sort of background workers. I initialize 1 WebBrowser object (new WebBrowser();) on each thread and do specific tasks.

Comment: WebBrowser objects are visual components. If you're just sending requests and receiving responses, you'd do better with WebRequest object.

Comment: can you create the webbrowser controls in different processes? WinInet settings are process-wide, so do WinInet sessions.

Comment: This idea is so crazy it *just might work*. :-)

Comment: @deadlock: Did you got this running?? If yes, then could you please provide information about how you did it. I am trying to do the same thing, but in C++.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe another approach would be in order.

You could spawn a WebRequest in the background threads and set a different proxy for each one.
After you receive the data, then you can easily load it in a WebBrowser to play with it.

Comment: Actually I am trying to use webBrowser to send and not to receive data.

Answer (score 1):

Since the WebBrowser is just an instance of the IE, it is impossible to set the Proxy for it.
(Unless you tweak the registry, but it it's not individually)

Answer (score 0):

As maor said, you won't be able to do a proxy per browser setup with WebBrowser.  Instead, if you have control over the proxy, you might want to see what options it has for identifying a session (request/response).  You might be able to, from the one proxy, tell which requests are *probably* coming from which WebBrowser controls depending on URLs and headers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using unmanaged code it can be achieved, it may help:

http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/12/23/1330.aspx