# Multiple Instances of IE with different proxies

Tags: c#

Is it possible to open multiple instances of Internet Explorer using different proxies for each? Would there be any issues multi threading instances of IE?

I was thinking about using WatiN, but I'm open to suggestions if anyone has an alternative solution.

Thanks

Comment: Depending on your requirements, a proxy.pac file _might_ be an alternate solution. Can you give us more details?

Answer (score 0):

IE uses the basic WinInet proxy configuration, AFAIK it won't be possible.

Hope [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534856/how-to-set-webbrowser-proxy) might be useful.