# Using proxy with WebBrowser and WebRequest, how to include username and password?

Tags: c#, proxy

I got this from [Load web browser with web response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172239/how-to-load-web-browser-with-web-response). and am wondering how I can use this code to use proxies that need a username and password to be able to work.

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
webRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy(host, port);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser.DocumentStream = receiveStream;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var webProxy = new WebProxy(host,port);
webProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
webRequest.Proxy = webProxy;
```